# TableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation Very Slow

Tags: ios, uitableview, delete-row

I have a table which may have several hundred rows, all with different heights.  Whenever a user deletes a row, the call:

```
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

takes a very long time to execute (around 2.5s).

Is there an alternative call to this one or any way to speed it up?  Thank you!

Comment: This method will also call some method of data source delegate, I think that is where it is stuck, can you show how you implement the data source delegate of `UITableView` ?

Comment: be sure to call it on the main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `estimatedRowHeight` of `UITableView` to speed it up.

> Providing a nonnegative estimate of the height of rows can improve the performance of loading the table view. If the table contains variable height rows, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights when the table loads. Using estimation allows you to defer some of the cost of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling time.

In any case you should measure with Instruments which parts of your code are taking up the most time.

Comment: So far this seems to be the best option.  It definitely decreased time, though there are few undesired effects.  It is now breaking constraints and it's faster at the top of the table than the bottom (where I'm guessing it has to load all the heights above it).  Thanks!

Comment: Edit: Fixed constraint issue by adding a more accurate height.  Also fixed my table loading slowly.  Issue still exists at bottom of table but MUCH MUCH faster (0.5s instead of 2.5s)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Its a bit unethical, but it works like a charm.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 if([textArray count]>0){
  [self deleteRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
} //method fired when u select a row, which calls a method
}

-(void)deleteRowAtIndexPath:(int) indexPath{ //this method removes the data in the array from which the tableview is being populated
[textArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath];
[self.tableView reloadData]; //after deleting the data from the array it reloads the tableview
 }
```

textArray is a NSMutableArray,from which the tableview is being populated.

But this dsnt have any animations.